# Select interpreter of docker container in the vscode

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

In vscode, we can install the python extension, then select the interpreter which we want, like python in the conda environment.

So we can use "shift" + "enter" key for running the code line by line in the terminal.
For managing different virtual environment, using docker container is a better way.

If I already install the docker, and pull the python image. How to select the interpreter which is created in the docker container? Not just remote to the docker container.

Comment: The image tag selects the Python version, not the IDE.

Answer (score 36):

Tested on VSCode 1.61:

1. Install the `Remote-Containers` extension
2. Build/start the Docker container
3. Open the Command Palette and type `Remote-Containers: Attach to Running Container...`, then select the running Docker container
4. VSCode will restart and reload
5. On the `Get Started` page, click the `Open...` and enter the path to the Docker volume mounted to your source code. It must be set to the same path as `WORKDIR` in your `Dockerfile-local`, e.g. to `/app`.
6. Install the `Python` extension on the container
7. Open the Command Palette and type `Python: Select Interpreter`, then select the Docker interpreter
8. Open the Command Palette and type `Python: Configure Tests`, then select the framework you use

Source: https://dev.to/alvarocavalcanti/setting-up-a-python-remote-interpreter-using-docker-1i24

**UPD #1.** `Remote development extensions` seem to be one of the main focuses in VSCode development currently, e.g. the newer versions have got the `Remote explorer` Activity tab enabled by default, which allows much more intuitive approach to connecting to Docker containers. Check release notes here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/tree/main/remote-release-notes

**UPD #2.** Nowadays you should use Dev Containers instead of Remote Containers

See the docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers

1. Create `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`

```
{
    "name": "My Devcontainer",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "app",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}",
    "customizations": {
        ...
```

Docs: https://containers.dev/implementors/json_reference/

2. Add your `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml`, `.env` to `.devcontainers`

```
...
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile

    volumes:
      - ../..:/workspaces:cached

    env_file: .env
...
```

3. Use `Dev containers: Open folder in container` and `Dev containers: Rebuild container` prompts to proceed

Comment: Seems like Step 3., 4. and 5. got simplified: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/attach-container

Comment: it is not the same as having just remote interpreter

Answer (score 0):

inside your `devcontainer.json` file that vscode created you have the `image` key and its value is the route to the image, if you want to use to change the python version you can do so there or using the quick instructions in vscode docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_quick-start-open-an-existing-folder-in-a-container)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible, I am afraid you must remote to the docker container.

I really can't imagine out you taking a python interpreter in Linux to work on windows directly.

Comment: You can do it with Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to have vscode to work on a local project and run it with a docker-based interpreter, the solution is: mounting the local project directory to the docker container that contains the interpreter, then in vscode open the project directory (mounted) from the container.

How to mount your project directory:

```
docker run -v /user/localproject:/root/mountedproject
```

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

I have tested it. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the extensions you want/need are installed in the container. Click Extensions on the left hand side to see which are installed locally and which are installed within the container.

Install everything within the container that you typically use locally (particularly Python and Pylance). You'll see a 'Install in Dev Container' button. Install everything you need, then restart VS Code and you should be good to go.

[image: Example showing the install in Dev Container button]

Example showing the install in Dev Container button