# Proper python environment for Visual Studio Code linter with my cookiecutter-django site being developed in a container?

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, cookiecutter-django

I am building a website with django in a docker container. All has been generated with cookiecutter-django following the official cookiecutter-django documentation Getting Up and Running Locally With Docker. The site runs well, I can develop without any problem. But I want to develop with Visual Studio Code and I can't choose the right python environment for the linter. Should I generate a copy of the python environment with the requirements just for the linter?

Here is my docker file :

```
version: '3'

volumes:
[my site name]_local_postgres_data: {}
[my site name]_local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
django:
build:
context: .
dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
image: [my site name]_local_django
container_name: [my site name]_local_django
depends_on:
- postgres
- mailhog
volumes:
- .:/app:z
env_file:
- ./.envs/.local/.django
- ./.envs/.local/.postgres
ports:
- "8000:8000"
command: /start

postgres:
build:
context: .
dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
image: [my site name]_production_postgres
container_name: [my site name]_local_postgres
volumes:
- [my site name]_local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
- [my site name]_local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
env_file:
- ./.envs/.local/.postgres

docs:
image: [my site name]_local_docs
container_name: [my site name]_local_docs
build:
context: .
dockerfile: ./compose/local/docs/Dockerfile
env_file:
- ./.envs/.local/.django
volumes:
- ./docs:/docs:z
- ./config:/app/config:z
- ./[my site name]:/app/[my site name]:z
ports:
- "9000:9000"
command: /start-docs

mailhog:
image: mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.0
container_name: [my site name]_local_mailhog
ports:
- "8025:8025"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a plugin, such as [Dev Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers), to attach to a remote python interpreter in the docker container. There's another SO answer that has more details on how to get it all going if the documentation is not enough for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72465679/11264793